# Getting SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field when trying to reassign approval request

Tags: soql, quote

I got the following error when trying to reassign the approval in the quote reassign approval request.

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested
>   field: Product2.Terms_And_Conditions_Eng__c

I understand what's the error. However, when I am trying to use the debug log to debug it and I could not find which apex class is causing this issue.

I'm lost about where is this error triggered.

Comment: Assuming you can repeat the process, the debug log should show at the appropriate debug level, all SOQL calls in the transaction. The reference to the field could be in a class far away from the class that does the SOQL query

Answer (score 0):

Without posting your entire codebase, noone here will be able to give a definitive answer. That said, do the following:

Set up Eclipse with the Force.com IDE and create a new project for your org.
Do a global search for 'Terms_And_Conditions_Eng__c'.

Unless you have a lot of code, you should be able to find where exactly this field is being referenced without first being retrieved in the preceding SOQL query.

Comment: I don't have the code. I really don't know where is this error trigger. In the debug log, I couldn't find which apex class. If I do, then I would have posted the code. I will definitely try to use Eclipse with Force.com IDE to do a global search. Hope that I can find the apex class.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue in the end?

Comment: Not yet, because I am busy working another integration project. I will go back to take a look very soon.